# Esper / NEsper EPL event statement

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper, nesper

I'm pretty new in NEsper/Esper. I want to catch the event when two event occur less than 3 seconds, in other words when the timestamp difference between two events is smaller than 3 seconds. How can I define the EPL statement?
For example, the event is a Tick (which contains attributes- symbol, price and timestamp). When a Tick occurs after previous Tick less than 3 seconds, the second Tick should be captured. How can I write the EPL statement "select * from StockTick(symbol='anySymbol')...."?
Thanks in advance.
Narsu

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways. Lets use match-recognize. It seems to do what you want.

```
select * from SymbolTick
match_recognize (
  partition by symbol
  measures E1 as e1, E2 as e2
  pattern (E1 E2)
  define 
    E2 as E1.timestamp.before(E2.timestamp, 3)
)
```

You can [read up on "before" and "after"](http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.6.0/reference-esper/html_single/index.html#datetime-method-after). I think maybe I didn't get it right so please check and test.
For numeric timestamps one could instead do "E2.timestamp - E1.timestamp <= 3000".

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I've tried your suggestion but got an additional Debug: Methode: StatementAIFactoryProvider_a005f40a456a9945474e4589a045a04a1e67c126_0.M18, Codegen: target = CurrentTimestamp... How can I avoid this Debug message? Could you hep me?

Comment: what is a "debug"? are you taking about debug level logging?

Comment: it comes the message in console when I test it in debug mode -   Debug: Methode: StatementAIFactoryProvider_a005f40a456a9945474e4589a045a04a1e67c126_0.M18, Codegen: target = CurrentTimestamp...

Comment: "test it in debug mode"? you Java app? All debug messages can be ignored. Debug messages are for consumption when interested what is going on internally and would be of no use to you.